# How to see that what disks are on a QLogic FC adapter on linux?

Tags: suse

So that example I can check:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 23 11:20 scsi-3600508e000000000XXXe71e04ffYYY0f -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 23 11:20 scsi-3600508e000000000XXXe71e04YYY1f0f-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 23 11:20 scsi-3600508e000000000XXXe71e04fYYYf0f-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 23 14:15 scsi-360080e5000230fc0000001ca4XXX8e06 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 23 14:15 scsi-360080e500023139c000001cf4dXXXe68 -> ../../sde
```

that sda is a physical RAID disk and the other two is FC.

Comment: maybe this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-fibre-channel-device-information/

Comment: maybe "lsscsi" is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
systool -c fc_host -v
```